# passing parameters to a Delphi Datasnap REST Server

Tags: rest, delphi, parameters

I'm trying to figure out how passing parameters work in REST-server I want to create in Delphi. Starting point is a Datasnap REST application sample, which has a ReverseString method. I want to use something like http://localhost:8080/ReverseString?value=hello, which should call the ReverseString method.

Can anyone help me out please ?

Regards,
Arthur

Comment: Start by doing what every developer must do, [read the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Tutorial:_Using_a_REST_DataSnap_Server_with_an_Application)

Comment: Yes, I do understand that, and I did. The point is that so far I only have seen samples about a REST Server getting request by a REST Client created in Delphi as well. I want to create a REST Server in Delphi, and the request will come via a browser. 
And yes, I have seen that the parameters are passed after slashes like localhost:8080/ReverseString/Param 1/Param 2. But that is not what I am looking for and I cannot find any information on that. That is why I am asking for help.

Comment: Well the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DataSnap_REST_Messaging_Protocol) states that there are 2 ways to pass parameters, one is via slashes and the other is via the http body. It seems that Datasnap has no support for query parameters (what you are looking for)